# Adjust fontsize in fixed-height/width table cells in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a a printable schedule as table with fixed height/width cells.
Cells contains names and I don't want that the names do line breaks.

Is there a way to dynamically adjust the font-size so that there will be no linebreaks or hiding text?

Maybe someone knows a good plugin or snippet for that issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping the contents of each cell with another element (table cells don't support `overflow :hidden`) with `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden` and reducing the `font-size` of that element until it's contents fit into it.

Example code:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>cell</span></td>
      <td><span>another cell</span></td>
      <td><span>yet another cell</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td span {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('td span').each(function() {
    var fontSize = 100;
    while (this.scrollWidth > $(this).width() && fontSize > 0) {
      // adjust the font-size 5% at a time
      fontSize -= 5;
      $(this).css('font-size', fontSize + '%');
    }
  });
});
```

[Working version of the example (JSBin)](http://jsbin.com/ecuji3/2).