# Align table rows of two tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have two tables horizontally next to each other. Everything is aligned initially. However, when the element inside one cell of the left table increases in size, it wraps and increases the cell height. How can I align two tables even with the left cell height increased?

Here is the image of what it looks like:

Without wrapping:

[image: without wrapping]

With wrapping:

[image: with wrapping]

Comment: Maybe you could use [https://datatables.net/](https://datatables.net/) ? Could this library be useful for you?

Comment: Why don't you use a single table only if you want same height. If you use single table you wont have to worry about aligning the tables every time there is a difference in height.

Comment: Because I was supposed to make the site responsive, I used two tables so that they wrap on mobile size. I am aware that there are ways to make it responsive with a single table, and that's what I did at first, then I was told that's not okay... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you have two options.

1. Use single table so that entire row will have same height. Or
2. Use div instead of table because div has overflow option. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514069/adjust-fontsize-in-fixed-height-width-table-cells-in-javascript-jquery)

Update after comment:
If you can use jquery, you could do it on page load. Refer this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/434036/)

Note: `height` attributes for both table's row and `class` name. Un-comment jquery line number 3 and execute.

Comment: So there's no way to do it if I have two tables?

Comment: There is a way if you use jquery where you can dynamically check height of the row in first table and set same height in second table on page load. But this increases complexity. using div is easy and more flexible. Are you already using jquery? If yes, put your html code in question and i can help you with document.ready function code to update row.

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking about checking row height with javascript and setting the height for the second table. Anyway, I can't really post the code, its too long, 900+ lines. Also, if I were to do that on page load, wouldn't it only do it once? what if the user zooms in or out?

Comment: Zoom will do same effect on both tables.In your case, rows will be identical on page load so both table will remain same. you can zoom in / zoom out in fiddler in my example. :)